# „Abschn.“ trennen

Tags: abbreviation, hyphenation

Darf man eigentlich „Abschn.“ (Abkürzung von „Abschnitt“) am Zeilenende wie „Ab-schn.“ trennen? Warum oder warum nicht? In http://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6214 fand ich nichts dazu.

Comment: Keine Antwort auf die Frage, aber wenn die Abkürzung schon zu lang ist, warum dann nicht einfach ausschreiben? Ob "erlaubt" oder nicht, es sähe in meinen Augen ein bisschen albern aus, eine Abkürzung zu trennen.

Comment: @infinitezero Zu „warum dann nicht einfach ausschreiben?“: laut Richtlinien des Verlegers soll's abgekürzt werden. Zu „albern“: klar und wenn man's nicht trennt, kann sich mitunter eine zu lange/kurze Zeile bilden, sodass ein schwerwiegenderes Problem an einer anderen Stelle auftritt. Also, grob gesagt, wenn man's nicht trennt, kann's manchmal noch alberner woanders aussehen.

Comment: Geek dafür ist doch in der Regel justified alignment da. Nichtsdestotrotz, im Angesichts des Kontextes sicherlich eine interessante Frage.

Comment: Wenn du nach den Richtlinien des Verlegers abkürzt, warum fragst du den dann nicht, ob du auch trennen sollst?

Comment: @infinitezero Ich hab sehr viel Text gerade in justified alignment.

Comment: @tofro Wenn hier nichts kommt, tue ich das. Aber … einige Leute dort, so wie ich sie kenne, sagen höchst wahrscheinlich „OK, G**gle“ und können vermutlich dann auf dieser Webseite landen. Zirkelschluss. Bingo!

Comment: Ich finde die Vorstellung, dass ein "Ab-" mehr oder weniger in der Zeile zu einem "schwerwiegenden Problem an anderer Stelle" führen kann, nicht so wirklich überzeugend. Aber die Frage finde ich interessant.

Comment: @HalvarF Ich kann dir leider wegen Nondisclosure-Agreement kein konkretes Beispiel zitierenn. Aber ich hab ein paar direkt vor meinen Augen. Zum Beispiel ragt „Abschn.“ ohne Trennung etwas in den Rand an einer Stelle hinaus und es entsteht der Eindruck, der Satz wäre in der ersten Zeile zu Ende, während er hingegen tatsächlich in der zweiten Zeile mit der Abschnittsnummer weitergeht. An einer anderen Stelle geht „Abschn.“ voll in die zweite Zeile und es entsteht optisch sehr viel Leerraum in der ersten Zeile und die zweite Zeile sieht optisch sehr gedrängt aus.

Comment: @HalvarF  An einer dritten Stelle geht „Absch.“ in die zweite Zeile und dadurch wird der enthaltende Absatz eine Zeile länger, was bewirkt, dass eine nachfolgende Abbildung auf die nächste Seite rutscht, während sie semantisch besser auf derselben Seite stünde. Und so weiter.

Comment: Wenn Deine Abbildungen wegen so was hin- und herrutschen, benutzt Du die falsche Satzsoftware?

Comment: @Raketenolli Es ist Absicht, dass sie rutschen. Du willst die bestmögliche Platzierung automatisch haben, statt die Abbildungen fest an einer Stelle zu verankern und womöglich halbvolle oder überlaufende Seiten zu haben.

Answer (score 1):

Es gibt die Regel, dass mehrteilige Abkürzungen (z.B. "z.B.") am Zeilenende nicht auseinanderzunehmen sind (was durch ein geschütztes "halbes" Leerzeichen abgefangen werden soll). Eine Trennung einer Abkürzung würde faktisch aus einer einteiligen eine mehrteilige Abkürzung machen und diese Regel brechen.

Ich würde daher empfehlen, auf gar keinen Fall Abkürzungen auch noch zu trennen.

Comment: Danke! Selbst würde ich „Ab-schn.“ nie als eine mehrteilige Abkürzung missverstehen, weil bei mir "-" mitten in einem Wort nie für eine Auslassung steht. Aber ich bin durch meinen eigenen Text stark voreingenommen. Wie sehen das die anderen?

Comment: Ich denke, hier sollte man "-teilig" sehr wörtlich verstehen. Und ein Trennstrich erzeugt nunmal zwei Teile.

Comment: Ist es nicht so, dass die von dir erwähnte Regel zu mehrteiligen Abkürzungen eigentlich nur Beispiele auflistet, in denen der erste Teil mit Punkt aufhört? Ferner verstehe ich die von dir erwähnte Regel so, dass man die Trennung eben nur vermeidet, aber nicht kategorisch verbietet. Sprich, wenn die Nichttrennung zu einem optisch schlechteren Ergebnis woanders führt, ist abzuwägen, was besser/schlechter aussieht, statt diese Regel knallhart durchzusetzten.

Comment: Optik vs. Verständlichkeit - würde ich in der Lyrik und Buchmalerei (mittelalterliche Schriften) gelten lassen. Moderne Schriften, die eigentlich den Inhalt transportieren wollen, sollten im Zweifel Les- und Verstehbarkeit vor optischen Eindruck stellen.

Comment: Es gibt Grenzen der guten Optik. Typographie ist nicht umsonst ein eigenes Fach. Ferner kann Umbruchsvermeidung generell Textverschiebung hervorrufen und sich auf die Verständlichkeit negativ auswirken — einfach weil sich Text zufällig so verschob, wie du das nicht möchtest.

Answer (score 0):

Die von Dir verlinkte Regel ist sehr deutlich:

> **§ 107**
> Mehrsilbige Wörter kann man am Ende einer Zeile trennen.

Der erklärende Text sagt außerdem

> Getrennt werden können nur mehrsilbige Wörter.

Da "Abschn." nur einen einzigen Vokal enthält, besteht es meinem Verständnis nach auch nur aus einer Silbe und kann somit nicht getrennt werden.

Die Fragen, ob man "Abschn." eventuell zweisilbig ausspricht oder ob Abkürzungen Wörter im Sinne der entsprechenden Regeln sind, überlasse ich anderen.

Comment: Danke! Hört sich vernünftig an. Also geht's jetzt um die (m.E. einfachere) Frage, wie viele Silben „Abschn.“ eigentlich hat. Kann jemand die Ansicht bestätigen/widerlegen, „Abschn.“ habe eine Silbe?

Comment: @GeekestGeek Ob die Definition einer Silbe (die ja eigentlich Bestandteil eines *vollständigen* Wortes ist) auch für eine Abkürzung gilt, wage ich zu bezweifeln (weil "Abschn." immer als "Abschnitt" *gelesen* wird - niemand liest die tatsächliche Abkürzung aus).

Comment: @tofro Betrachte etwa „Kap.“ als Abkürzung von „Kapitel“. Nehmen wir als natürlich™ (ich gebe zu, der Begriff ist vage) an, dass entweder beides *lang* ist (3 Silben, 7 Buchstaben) oder beides *kurz* ist (1 Silbe, 3 Buchstaben).  Demnach, wenn du „Kap.“ als Abkürzung von „Kapitel“ als dreisilbig verstehen würdest, würdest du also vermutlich analog dazu „p.“ (als „pitel“) als 5 Buchstaben ansehen. Dann würde Regel §107 E1, die die Abtrennung einzelner Vokale verbietet, nicht greifen, und du würdest „Kap.“ als „Ka-p.“ trennen dürfen. Ich finde es aber sehr ungewöhnlich; du vermutlich auch.

Comment: @tofro Daher war eine der Annahmen/Prämissen in der vorigen Betrachtung auch ungewöhnlich. Ich finde, dass aus allen Annahmen die Annahme, dass „Kap.“ dreisilbig ist, die ungewöhnlichste. Wir lassen sie daher fallen und zählen „Kap.“ als eine Silbe. Analog dazu zählen wir „Abschn.“ als eine Silbe. Klingt's sinnvoll oder hab ich recht?

Comment: Zwar interpretierte ich „p“ oben als Vokal. Aber wenn du ihn als einen Konsonanten ansiehst, würde die Regel §107 E1 sowieso nicht greifen, und du würdest "Ka-p." erst mit Recht trennen dürfen.

Comment: @GeekestGeek Du hast meinen Kommentar fasch verstanden: "Kap." ist mMn nicht dreisilbig. Sondern es kann, weil es kein "Wort" im gängigen Sinn mehr, sondern eine Verstümmelung ist, gar keine Silben mehr haben - mMn haben nur Worte Silben.

Comment: @tofro Mit dieser Argumentation wäre „Abschn.“ auch kein Wort™.

Comment: @GeekestGeek Soisses. Es ist nur noch ein "Zeichen für ein Wort" - so wie "§" ein Zeichen für Paragraph und "km" ein Zeichen für "Kilometer" ist.

Comment: Aber mit dieser Argumentation wären dann einige Sätze wie „Wir sprechen über Wörter bzw. über Silben.“ gar keine Sätze. Denn nach meinem Verständnis (Mathe und Interpunktion beiseitegelassen) bestehen Sätze aus Wörtern.

Comment: Was die Zeichen angeht… Zwar sind physikalische Einheiten Zeichen und Interpunktion Zeichen. Aber ansonsten haben „bzw.“, „z.B.“, „udgl.“ … doch Satzfunktionen und unterscheiden sich drastisch von "km" und dem Komma, um Beispiele anzugeben.

Comment: @tofro Außerdem gibt's auch Abkürzungen ohne Punkte. „Azubi“ (Auszubildender), „U-Bahn“ (Untergrundbahn) oder „Schiri“ (Schiedrichter) etwa. Sind es nun Wörter oder doch nur Zeichen? Ich finde es etwas seltsam, den Abkürzungen wie „Kap.“ und „Abschn.“ den Wortstatus abzuerkennen, nur weil sie Punkte haben.

Comment: @tofro Außerdem… sind „Xnr.“ und „XBsp.“ nicht Abkürzungen für sehr viele Wörter X? Also wären dann nicht alles von „Einkommensteuerausfüllnr.“ bis „Rhabarberbarbarabarbarbarenbartbarbierbierbsp.“ (absichtlich übertrieben) Zeichen, die keine Wörter wären, und denen daher das Recht auf Trennung abgesprochen worden wäre? Das kann man so instruktiv machen, aber sinnvoll ist es dennoch, diese zwei Ungetüme zu trennen, etwa „Einkommen-steuerausfüllnr.“ oder „Rhabarberbarbarabarbar-barenbartbarbierbierbsp.“ oder ähnlich. Andere, kürzere Abkürzungen dürfen dann von mir aus auch getrennt werden.

Comment: Ein wichtiger Unterschied zwischen "Kap." und "Abschn." ist, dass "Kap" als eine Silbe gelesen werden kann. Dagegen kann "Abschn" als zwei Silben gelesen werden: "Ab" und "schn" (und ja, es gibt vokallose Silben).

Comment: @RHa Das kommt doch nur daher, dass *n* stimmhaft ist, also summbar. Oder habe ich was verpasst, und die Definition einer Silbe mache einen Unterschied zwischen stimmhaften und stimmlosen Konsonanten?

Comment: @GeekestGeek Ein Konsonant muss nicht stimmhaft sein, damit er eine Silbe tragen kann. Siehe z.B. s und r in Psst und Grr.

Comment: @Rha Deiner Argumentation nach wäre dann „schneit“ (etwa in „Es schneit“) zweisilbig: „schn“ und „eit“. Das wiederum wäre sehr, sehr dubiös. Genauso würde es sich mit „Schnitt“ verhalten, im Übrigen.

Comment: @GeekestGeek "schneit" ist nicht zweisilbig, man könnte es aber zweisilbig als schh-neit ausprechen, was jedoch niemand tut.

Comment: @RHa Eben. „Schn“ in „schneit“, „Schnitt“ und „Abschn.“ wird gleich ausgesprochen. Entweder ist es überall eine Silbe oder überall keine. Da du selber sagst, dass „schn“ in „schneit“ keine Silbe ist, ist es nach dir selbst auch in „Abschn.“ keine.

Comment: @GeekestGeek Der Punkt ist, dass *Abschn.* mit 2 Silben ausgesprochen werden kann, und zwar entweder als Ab-schnitt (mit i als Kern der zweiten Silbe) oder als Ab-schn mit sch als Kern der 2. Silbe. Es kann vielleicht auch als 1 Silbe ausgesprochen werden, aber das ist für einen Sprecher des Deutschen zumindest ziemlich schwierig.

Comment: @RHa Hm. Du müsstest irgendwie den Unterschied zwischen einsilbiger (angeblich schwieriger) und zweisilbiger Aussprache von „Abschn.“ (ohne -itt, angeblich leichter) klarmachen können, wenn der Unterschied nach deiner Meinung existiert. Ich behaupte, „schn.“ wird immer gleich ausgesprochen, ob in „schneit“, „schnitt“ oder „Abschn.“ und nie als eine eigenständige Silbe. Wenn du das Gegenteil behauptest, ist es dein gutes Recht, und in diesem Fall würde ich dich bitten, uns  bitte vorzusprechen, was du meinst, um uns es klar zu machen, und das Ergebnis auf einen Dateiaustauschserver hochzuladen.

Comment: @RHA  (Vielleicht hilft dir IPA oder so, aber der Unterschied könnte auch unter der Genauigkeit/Auflösung des Alphabets liegen.)